A better way to check which html tags are keyboard inputable?
I'm implementing a keyboard shortcut feature that works on a website.
However, I don't want the keyboard shortcut to work when the user writes a comment or post.
So I tried like this:
window.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {

  const { clientWidth, tagName, type, attributes } = document.activeElement || {};
  if(clientWidth && (
    (tagName == 'INPUT' && (
      type == 'text' ||
      type == 'password' ||
      type == 'number' ||
      type == 'email' ||
      type == 'tel' ||
      type == 'url' ||
      type == 'date' ||
      type == 'time' ||
      type == 'datetime-local' ||
      type == 'month' ||
      type == 'range' ||
      type == 'week' ||
      type == 'color' ||
      type == 'search'
    )) ||
    tagName == 'TEXTAREA' ||
    attributes.contenteditable?.value
  )) return;

  // shortcut action
});

This works fine. But it looks messy. Is there a better way than this? I don't mind if this only works on Chromium.

Why tagName == 'INPUT' is not enough?

Because radio buttons, check boxes, etc. are not possible.

But why you care? Can your keyboard shortcut feature be executed via checkbox click? Why don't you directly check what keyboard keys were pressed in first place?

Because when the focus is <input type="checkbox">, keyboard shortcuts should work because the focus is not keyboard typing, and when <input type="text"> is keyboard typing, keyboard shortcuts should not work.

I think you need to re-think your approach. What it has to do with focus if you are listening for keypress event?

I don't mind any other events or other approaches. However, I just want to use simple keystrokes as shortcuts that do not combine with special keys, such as ctrl, alt, or shift. Another problem is that I cannot predict what html tags will be on the screen (there are WYSIWYG editors that also allow radios and checkboxes).

For example, let's say that a specific function operates when you press the A key on the keyboard. Then, when people are typing to write a comment and their sentence contains a, the shortcut will be triggered. I want to stop this. But it should work in all non-typing situations. The shortcut key should work even when the focus is on any user-created radio button. This is why I check which tag is currently focused.
